# Replace last comma separated value by another using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string as follows :

```
var str = "a,b,c,a,e,f";
```

What I need is replace the last comma separated element by another.

```
ie, str = "a,b,c,a,e,anystring";
```

I have done it using `split` method and adding it to make a new string. But it is not working as expected

What I done as follows :

```
var str = "a,b,c,d,e,f";

var arr = str.split(',');

var res = str.replace(arr[5], "z");
alert(res);
```

Is there any regex to help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with regex **[`/,[^,]+$/`](https://regex101.com/r/uD3dR0/1)** to match the last string

```js
var str = "a,b,c,d,e,old";
var res = str.replace(/,[^,]+$/, ",new");
// or you can just use
// var res = str.replace(/[^,]+$/, "new");
document.write(res);
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

Or you can just use regex `str.replace(/[^,]+$/, "new");`

```js
var str = "a,b,c,d,e,old";
var res = str.replace(/[^,]+$/, "new");
document.write(res);
```

---

Or using **[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** , replace the last array value with new string and then join it again using **[`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** method

```js
var str = "a,b,c,d,e,old";
var arr = str.split(',');
arr[arr.length - 1] = 'new';
var res = arr.join(',');
document.write(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a `String.substring()` of `String.lastIndexOf()`:

```
function replaceStartingAtLastComma(str, rep){
  return str.substring(0, (str.lastIndexOf(',')+1))+rep;
}
console.log(replaceStartingAtLastComma('a,b,c,d,e,f', 'Now this is f'));
```